# Select a field, and count an another field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

In a webshop, i am listing out the orders from mysql to create a report. I want to see, that when(date) and how many orders are.

Orders in my table now:

- 2017-09-12
- 2017-09-13
- 2017-09-13
- 2017-09-13
- 2017-09-11

How can i count, that how many orders are on 2017-09-13?

My sql:

```
SELECT datum FROM rendeles_adatok ORDER BY datum ASC LIMIT $actual, $row_per_page
```

What i mean:
[image]

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That wont give the number of orders on a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group your results by `datum`:

```
SELECT   datum, COUNT(*) 
FROM     rendeles_adatok 
GROUP BY datum -- Here!
ORDER BY datum ASC 
LIMIT    $actual, $row_per_page
```

Comment: And i have count all fiedls from the table? Not just the id or the date field?

Comment: I added a pohoto to my question!